# Need for iid in MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood, bayes, supervised-learning, nonparametric, iid

I am studying about parametric estimation in supervised learning using maximum likelihood estimation. Here is what I learned:

1. Separate our training data according to class; i.e., we have c data sets Y1,....Yc, sample in Yi are independently and identically distributed (iid) according to p(y|wi).
2. We assume that the form of p(y|wi) is known and uniquely determined by a parameter vector Θ (we will write p(y|wi,Θ)).
3. We assume that Θi and Θj are functionally independent.
4. Then, the problem reduces to solving c separate and
   independent problems like this: given the data Y = {y1, ..., yn} iid according to p(y|Θ), find the estimate of Θ = (Θ1, ..., Θp).

wi is class i.

My question is what is the need for iid? What happens if we don't assume iid? My probability and statistics isn't really that good, so if possible try to give a simple answer. Thanks.

Comment: i.i.d. condition is the common assumption imposed in likelihood method in order to formulate the likelihood function. Without i.i.d. assumption, the likelihood function would be much more complicated (either to write or to solve).

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thank you... one last question... the reason why we are trying to maximize in MLE is because we want to maximize the likelihood of the samples in Yi are from the distribution p(y|wi). I am correct in thinking this way?

Comment: yes, but be cautious that, as a parametric method, MLE works best only when your assumption about your model (i.e., your $p(y|w_i)$) is correct.

Comment: @Zhanxiong is there a difference between, 
1. maximize the likelihood that the samples in Yi are from the distribution p(y|wi), and
2. MLE will pick the distribution that is the most likely one that my data is drawn from.
If there is a difference, then which one is MLE for the parametric estimation in supervised learning?